# How i can use local ms-access db file in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How i can use local ms-access db file in Silverlight 4.
I want to read records from local ms-access file of any user who installed Out Of Browser Application on his/her system.
Same as we do with excel records. Looking forward to get results from experts.

Answer (score 0):

In OOB with Elevated Trust you can use the `AutomationFactory` to get access to COM objects on Windows:-

```
dynamic conn = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
```

In C# you use the new `dynamic` type to hold references to COM objects that you can then manipulate in "Script" like manner.